# Path variable: Find folder path of specific file

Tags: linux, cygwin, environment-variables, msysgit, path-variables

On Linux and other Unix-likes, how do I find the path to a specific file that I can use because of the `PATH` environment variable? For example, if I can use, from the command line:

```
ls # technically the file name is "ls.exe"
```

is there a way I can find the path of the `ls.exe` file explicitly without looking through the `PATH` variable myself (i.e. maybe have a program search through it but not look myself)?

I understand there are many pitfalls/caveats of doing this, for example a `PATH` can be a file or even part of a file (I think), plus symlinks, etc. could make it unreliable, but I'm looking for general use cases.

The reason I am asking is I have Windows with msysgit so I have A LOT of folders in my path, and searching every one would be annoying & time-consuming, not to mention harder because of Windows limitations, but I can still presumably use almost anything Linux can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $ type ls.exe
   ls.exe is /usr/bin/ls.exe
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize it would be this easy. Does this work for all environment variables or just PATH?

Comment: By the way, this works whether you include the extension or not, i.e., whether you say `type ls` or `type ls.exe`. I'm sure you knew that, just throwing it out there for people reading this who don't know.

Comment: Why does this work? Where is the `type` file in the computer? I could just search, but I'm asking for the benefit of others who come to this page.

Comment: $ "type type" ... 
"type is a shell builtin"